# How to know data is receiving or Not when user is already Connected to Internet?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-internet

I am able to know Device is connected to Internet(whether connected with wifi\ mobile data) or not but i want to know is **data is receiving from Current connection or not**, now I want to check if data receiving speed is 0 kbps app should notify user like in Windows  wifi status turns to **limited** if data is not receiving from connected Network. Basically I am playing a HLS video and want to get data receiving speed while video is playing. How can i achieve this ? thanks in Advance

Comment: a hack: in the background try to connect to google.com.
You know the data transferred (google page size along with headers) and also the start and end time of your request.

I am not aware of any library or android method which allows this otherwise

Comment: @RusheelJain why should i connect to google.com in background can u explain ?

Comment: [You can find your answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)